# Кодировка в приложении

Tags: json, кодировка, java

Здравствуйте, есть небольшой лаунчер написанный на java для запуска игры. В лаунчере есть дата и заголовки последних новостей. Недавно, после публикации новой новости, обнаружили, что заголовок одной новости неправильно отображается в лаунчере. Лаунчер делает HTTP запрос по ссылке http://api.ensemplix.ru/1.0/server/news/, откуда получает JSON ответ.

Изображение проблемы:

[image: img]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это исправить?

public class News {

```
private static List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<News>();

private int id;
private String header;
private String created;

    public News(int id, String header, long created) {
            this.id = id;
            this.header = header;
            this.created = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy").format(new Date(
                            created * 1000));
    }

    public static void loadNews() throws Exception {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.ensemplix.ru/1.0/server/news/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            String result = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += new String(line.getBytes(), "UTF8");
            }
            reader.close();

            if (result != null) {
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONArray newsArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject newsObject = (JSONObject) newsArray.get(i);
                            newsObject = (JSONObject) newsObject.get("news");

                            int id = Integer.parseInt((String) newsObject.get("id"));
                            String header = String.valueOf(newsObject.get("header"));
                            long created = Long.parseLong((String) (newsObject.get("created")));

                            News news = new News(id, header, created);
                            newsList.add(news);
                    }
            }
    }

    public int getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
            return header;
    }

    public String getCreated() {
            return created;
    }

    public static List<News> getNews() {
            if (!newsList.isEmpty()) {
                    return newsList;
            } else {
                    return null;
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Телепаты уже пьяны в стельку в честь нового года. 

Проблема судя по всему в коде лаунчера.

Comment: Очень ценный комментарий. Лучшее вообще ничего не пишите.

Comment: Видимо Вы ручками разбираете utf-8. Но кто его знает. Кода никакого нет. json по ссылке выглядит валидным.

Comment: @Владислав Голуб, Вы ждете ответа:  
У Вас ошибка в строке 115, нужно было писать не **так**, а **так**.  
?  

@Владислав Голуб, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Тёзка, вам просто намекнули, что из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно, и что вы с таким вопросом вряд ли дождётесь осмысленных ответов. Примите это как помощь, и (если конечно вам нужно ехать, а не шашечки) уточните вопрос. Поскольку JSON-ответ выглядит правильно, очевидно, что ошибка не в нём.

Comment: Я описал проблему так, как она есть - проблема с отображениям русских слов. Я рассчитывал, что с подобной проблемой встречались другие люди и могут сказать, какие тут могли возникнуть сложности. Я добавил код.

Comment: @Владислав Голуб: не-не-не, вы делаете конвертацию неправильно. Вы сначала конвертируете `BufferedReader`'ом в строку в непонятной кодировке, потом вытаскиваете из этой строки байты в надежде, что они не испортились при конвертациях, и конвертируете снова. Делайте не так, сообщите `InputStreamReader`'у нужную кодировку, пусть он сам внутри перекодирует. (Ну и трюк с `GetBytes` выбросите.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы все сделал не так - просто использовал бы [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) - он полностью скрывает всю эту порнографию с парсингом JSon строки и проч. халабуду:

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
Gson gson=new Gson();
News news[]=gson.fromJson(reader, News[].class);
```

Просто и эффективно.

**Update**

По здравому размышлению корень проблемы, на мой взгляд, в строке предполагающей чтение в дефолтной кодировке:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Это надо писать с явным указанием кодировки UTF-8:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

И не мучаться строкой "с перекодировкой" полученной уже корявой строки в UTF-8:

```
result += new String(line.getBytes(), "UTF8"); //это лишнее
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам скорее всего пересылаются не чистые данные, а полностью текстовый файл в UTF-8.

В начале там идет специальный символ ([byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), он скорее всего всё портит.

Соответственно есть два варианта:

1. Чтобы сервер передавал без BOM
2. Удалять этот символ (BOM) самому

Comment: Ну это верно если только самому парсить UTF-8 строку, в данном случае неприменимо.

Comment: Сервер этот символ может и в сам json запихнуть. 

Т.е. прислать, например {"object":{"param1":"*Вася","param2":"Петя"}} (вместо * - бом)

Если он Васю и Петю из файла читает.

Comment: Ну и пусть пихает, вы же не собираетесь вручную резать его - см. код в моем ответе

Comment: Не, я против вашего варианта ничего не имею ) А вообще хотелось бы увидеть оригинал ответа от сервера.

Comment: @Russtam [ткни сюда](http://api.ensemplix.ru/1.0/server/news/,) и увидишь - нормальный UTF-8 ответ